# Emulated App doesn't match the layout

Tags: java, android, webview

[On the emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jld2Q.jpg) [in Android Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iL4iF.jpg)So the app i am creating doesn't match the layout file on the emulator(LG G5) personal phone. I have read around and found constraints can be a problem so i've redone them all and it is still doing this. Recently i was attempting to import a library which failed but i undone all the i did do and just to clarify the edit text and imagebutton should be above the webview but appears underneath it when run through the emulator

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"

tools:context="com.equiware.mickeyt.equinox.MainActivity">


<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/options_menu"
    style="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ImageButton"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:contentDescription="@string/mr_button_content_description"
    android:onClick="showPopup"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/webView"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/search_bar"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_list"
    tools:ignore="OnClick" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/search_bar"
    style="@android:style/Widget.DeviceDefault.Light.EditText"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="76dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_x="0dp"
    android:layout_y="0dp"
    android:background="@color/Transparent"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:hint="@string/search"
    android:imeOptions="normal|actionUnspecified|actionGo"
    android:singleLine="true"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/webView"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/options_menu"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
    tools:textSize="12sp"
    android:layout_marginRight="76dp" />

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webView"
    android:layout_width="361dp"
    android:layout_height="528dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/options_menu">

</WebView>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Please show us screenshots on the device and emulator so that we don't need to compile a project to see this in action.

Comment: remember emulated app is screen based on a specific device, when you deploy it, different screen size and pixels differentiates the outcome

Comment: the nexus 5 works great for my phones ive tried with others in the past but the nexus 5 seems to be the best matching the resolution and screen size